# Check access to SOAP/REST web service without invoke it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way to check access to SOAP or REST web service without invoke it?

I have an application where I input the URL and content type and header Accept details, but how to validate if these details are correct without invoke or execute the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least, you can validate the URI that has been entered using a method like this:

```vb
Public Shared Function IsValidUri(ByVal uriString As String) As Boolean
    Dim uri As Uri
    If Not uriString.Contains("://") Then uriString = "http://" & uriString

    If Uri.TryCreate(uriString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, uri) Then

        If Dns.GetHostAddresses(uri.DnsSafeHost).Length > 0 Then
            Return True
        End If
    End If

    Return False
End Function
```

However, unless you specifically know what content type and header accept details the server will always require, you would need to at least invoke the service and ensure you get a valid response.  This is exactly what the Add Service Reference in Visual Studio does when you use a URL to add a web service reference.